# Nested PDO queries fail?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the follow code:

```
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT pageid FROM webpages WHERE ISNULL(deleted) ORDER BY sortindex"); 
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  switch ($row["pageid"]) {
  case "information":
    Write("  <li class='top'><a href='index.php?m=info' id='info' class='top_link'><span class='down'>Information</span></a>");
    Write("    <ul class='sub'>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=n'>News</a></li>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=e'>Events</a></li>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=m'>Minutes</a></li>");
    $subsql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY sortindex,category"); 
    while ($catrow = $subsql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&cat={$catrow["cid"]}'>{$catrow["category"]}</a></li>");
    Write("    </ul>");
    break;
  }
}
```

When I run it, I get "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /chroot/home/web/html/test.php on line 29" line 29 being the "while ($catrow..." line.

On my dev server though, it works.  What should I be checking to figure out how to make it work on the production server?  I have no idea why it would be failing.  If I move the code out of the first SQL loop, it works fine on production.  This works no problem:

```
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT pageid FROM webpages WHERE ISNULL(deleted) ORDER BY sortindex"); 
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  switch ($row["pageid"]) {
  case "information":
    Write("  <li class='top'><a href='index.php?m=info' id='info' class='top_link'><span class='down'>Information</span></a>");
    Write("    <ul class='sub'>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=n'>News</a></li>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=e'>Events</a></li>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=m'>Minutes</a></li>");
    Write("    </ul>");
    break;
  }
}
$subsql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY sortindex,category"); 
while ($catrow = $subsql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) Write("Cat: {$catrow["category"]}<br/>");
```

When I run that, the first loop runs then after that I get the category list fine.  I know I cannot exact Stack Overflow to troubleshoot my server, but if someone had an idea what kind of config tweak or other issue would cause this kind of behavior I would greatly appreciate any tips :)

Comment: what is `ISNULL(deleted)` ?

Comment: deleted is a datetime field in the MySQL to let me know the date/time the content person marked it as deleted.  I don't like to actually delete stuff, I just mark it as such and hide it away.  Kind of a "recycle bin" I suppose.  If I copy the query into phpMyAdmin and execute it there, I get results fine.

Comment: I am wondering what does Write() function do. Can't think what code it may be consist of.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should've changed those to echos for the example.  It's just a little thing I use (function Write($str) { echo "$str\n"; }).  I noticed when using echo if I have to "view source" on the output, it's hard to read with the stuff all crammed together so I use that to make it more legible.

Comment: there is a way better way to output neat HTML. [Just write it as is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2574797/285587)

Comment: True, but I've never been a fan of embedding bits of PHP amongst markup.  It just looks cluttered to me and makes it diffcult, IMO, to troubleshoot.  Just a personal preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statements not entirely fetched may block other statements to actually happen (hence the `$subsql` not being a valid PDO object). this might work:

```
$rows = $pdo->query("SELECT pageid FROM webpages WHERE ISNULL(deleted) ORDER BY sortindex")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  switch ($row["pageid"]) {
  case "information":
    Write("  <li class='top'><a href='index.php?m=info' id='info' class='top_link'><span class='down'>Information</span></a>");
    Write("    <ul class='sub'>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=n'>News</a></li>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=e'>Events</a></li>");
    Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&submode=m'>Minutes</a></li>");
    $subsql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY sortindex,category"); 
    while ($catrow = $subsql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) Write("      <li><a href='index.php?m=info&cat={$catrow["cid"]}'>{$catrow["category"]}</a></li>");
    Write("    </ul>");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was the problem, your modification works perfect on my prod server.  I wonder why it works on my dev one.  My dev one runs an older PHP, maybe that's something they fixed/changed in a later ver?  Well, either way, thanks a bunch!!

Comment: hmmm, might be in your dev server there's only one row returned by the first statement? this might help you: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: Nah, the database is the same between the two.  I'll read the docs though, thanks.